# Why it is necessary to compile the flatc executable file?

Tags: flatbuffers

Yesterday I compiled the necessary files to create the schemas but let me wondering why it was necessary to do all these steps to create the schemas, why those executables can't be shared directly as a release, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do provides a win32 executable for releases (https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/releases), and there are executables for Linux / OSX / Win for every commit and CI run here: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/actions

Providing executables for Linux that will serve everyone is relatively difficult, with every distro having different versions of glibc and Linux somehow being static linking unfriendly, 32 vs 64 bit etc. So the CI executable may or may not work for you.

On Windows, a single statically linked win32 executable works for everyone, and Windows people are less used to compiling things themselves, hence why we provide it.

Comment: Awesome didn't knew about this, thank you! (can't upvote yet, sorry!)